Long Android TextView
I am trying to build a simple scrolling text proof of concept. I don't want to use marquee as it need greater control. The issue I have is my text is being cropped at the width of the layout and nothing I do appears to fix the issue.
I have a simple empty FrameLayout:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

</FrameLayout>

In the MainActivity I dynamically add a TextView with a long string and then animate the scroll using a ValueAnimator. Here's my OnCreate function:
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FrameLayout fl = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame_layout);

        TextView scrollingText = new TextView(this);
        scrollingText.setText(R.string.long_content);
        scrollingText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        scrollingText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 32);
        scrollingText.setSingleLine(true);

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.BOTTOM);
        scrollingText.setLayoutParams(params);

        fl.addView(scrollingText);

        animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(1.0f, 0.0f);
        animator.setDuration(10000);
        animator.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
        animator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());

        animator.addUpdateListener(
                new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                        float progress = (float) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                        scrollingText.measure(0, 0);
                        float width = scrollingText.getMeasuredWidth();
                        float translationX = width*(progress-1);
                        scrollingText.setTranslationX(translationX);
                    }
                }
        );

        animator.start();
}

What I expect is the TextView to scroll across the screen, but the text in the TextView is cropped at the view width. I did a quick debug and the TextView getWidth() returns 1024, the width of the screen, but getMeasuredWidth() returns 3985, the width of text contained.
What do I need to do to display all the text in the view?

Could you add a visual prototype of what's expected?

To answer my own question, I just had to change the params width to the calculated version like so, where the scrollingTextWidth I got from getMeasuredWidth():
params = scrollingText.getLayoutParams();
params.width = scrollingTextWidth;
